# Clean up Django Ajax JSON GET Request

Tags: ajax, django, json

So I'm trying to use AJAX to load some data. I can get the data to load but it's stuck in json. How do I make it so it's cleaner & more human readable?

```
//jquery
$.get("/get_artwork", function(data) {
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
         $('.result').append("<br/> " + data + " ");
     });

#Views.py 
def get_artwork(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
    artwork = Artwork.objects.all()[1:]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = serializers.serialize("json", artwork, fields=('name','updated'),  indent=2, use_natural_keys=True)
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/javascript')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "This is an XHR POST request"
            # Here we can access the POST data
            print request.POST
    else:
        message = "Hello"
return HttpResponse(message)
```

and this is what renders:

```
[ { "pk": 3, "model": "artworks.artwork", "fields": { "updated": "2013-01-20T06:46:24Z" } }, { "pk": 2, "model": "artworks.artwork", "fields": { "updated": "2013-01-17T23:44:26Z" } }, { "pk": 1, "model": "artworks.artwork", "fields": { "updated": "2013-01-17T23:43:22Z" } } ]
```

How would I make this more human-readable? Thanks!

Comment: If you switch to built-in json, it has 'pretty print'/'indent' option: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html .

Comment: thanks. do you mind giving me an example? I don't know how I'd implement with ajax.

Comment: this is what happend `"[\n {\n \"pk\": 3, \n \"model\": \"artworks.artwork\", \n \"fields\": {\n \"updated\": \"2013-01-20T06:46:24Z\"\n }\n }, \n {\n \"pk\": 2, \n \"model\": \"artworks.artwork\", \n \"fields\": {\n \"updated\": \"2013-01-17T23:44:26Z\"\n }\n }, \n {\n \"pk\": 1, \n \"model\": \"artworks.artwork\", \n \"fields\": {\n \"updated\": \"2013-01-17T23:43:22Z\"\n }\n }\n]`

Comment: changing my code to be `new = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': '))
  return HttpResponse(new,mimetype='application/javascript')`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments you've left.. it seems your issue is downstream in the client (e.g. web browser). It is not clear what you mean by *stuck in JSON*. If you are using JavaScript to parse the JSON, you will need to use `JSON.parse()` to turn it into a native JavaScript object. If you are using jQuery and the `$.ajax()` method, you will need to set the `mimetype` to `application/json` for it to automatically parse it as JSON.

**UPDATE**

If you want to control *how* the JSON data is rendered in the browser, I suggest you parse the JSON response into a native JavaScript object and then iterate over objects and fields you want to render in the page. As an example, using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some-url/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        var i, k, li, obj, fields;

        for (i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
            obj = resp[i];
            // render obj pk or model name here... now iterate over fields
            fields = obj.fields;

            for (k of obj.fields) {
                li = $('<li>').text(k + ': ' + obj.fields[k]);
                // append the li to some element..
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. First off, I need to render the `JSON` in `HTML` and as of now, it's a dictionary inside of a list as opposed to just a dictionary. Changing the `mimtype=application/json` breaks it.

Comment: Django serializers are meant for generating and consuming [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).. so that is why your object is within an array. If you merely want to display JSON in a webpage, you can keep everything the way it is and render the JSON within a `<pre>` tag to ensure the newlines and tabs are rendered.

Comment: Thanks Byron. Basically, I want to show a list of these objects using an AJAX `GET` call. The only way I knew how to return is JSON. Do you know another way to do this?

Comment: What are you doing with that response to the AJAX call? As I suggested, you just wrap the raw JSON response within a HTML `<pre>` tag and put it into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Byron. I really need the data to be in a list.

Comment: So, `{"fields": {"updated": "2013-01-17T23:43:22Z"}, "model": "artworks.artwork",  "pk": 1}` as `<li>2013-01-17T23:43:22Z</li>`

Comment: user clicks button, ajax returns data, data comes back in a list of updated times.

Comment: Unfortunately you are spanning multiple technologies with your question and the scope of it seems to be changing as I provide solutions to my previous interpretation. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Byron. Perhaps I should have asked a better question.

Comment: the ajax method isn't working. perhaps it's something with my view?

Comment: Byron, I figured it out. The data I was sending back from my models was `JSON` and I should have made it simple `html` but I was under the impression that ajax requires `json` Thanks for your help.